# Post Build Event to fire Build of another project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

A quick Google search shows all sorts of options for pre & post build events but none seem to cover building multiple projects.

In my solution I have over 100 different projects (literally not an exaggeration) but at any one time I am only working one or two.

Often the two, three etc. being worked on have some connection and so changes to one means all three need to be rebuilt.

Rebuild ALL works but it takes minutes not seconds for all 100+ project to rebuild. Rebuild of just the one only works for the one.

Is there a way in pre build or post build to specify building another project(s).

The thought is when working for a week on say two projects I would specify in post build to also build project X.

Thanks

Comment: Open Project - Project Dependecies dialog in Visual Studio and fill dependencies for every project. This should give you desired effect, istead of using Post Build event.

Comment: @AlexFarber. Perfect. I am new and wasn't aware of such project linking...of course it makes perfect sense but still I didn't know. Change your comment to an answer and I will mark for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Project - Project Dependecies dialog in Visual Studio and fill dependencies for every project. This should give you desired effect, istead of using Post Build event.